# Two design questions from Ember.js framework;

Tags: ember.js

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way where I can use a button for showing/hiding content
   separately for every item in each loop? Because I only know how to
   toggle single property.
2. Is there a way where I can slowly show content not immediately

Comment: For the record, you should show some code. Check out the Ember tutorial. It shows how to do both of those things, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer to your first question:

Yes, see the demo: [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/115bc04d3f50abe39bb54459a65167b4?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C).

Basically, you need to manipulate `visible` property of each item in a loop and also add `{{if}}`to render your content only if `visible === true`. Code:

```
{{#each animals as |item|}}
  {{#if item.visible}}
     <b>{{item.name}} is visible!</b>
  {{/if}}
  <br/>
  <button onclick={{action (mut item.visible) (if item.visible false true)}}>{{if item.visible 'Hide' 'Show'}} {{item.name}}</button>
  <br/>
{{/each}}
```

An answer to your second question - you can use CSS transitions to achieve that. Basically, you can add class `show` to the element when you want to show it - and then add CSS transition to slowly fade in content.

Comment: so I have to add another property to my ember-data model to achieve the answer to the first question?

Comment: Yes, if you'd like to store if something is visible or not - then yes.

Comment: Thanks very much my friend I will use that definitely... :)

Comment: One note: if you don't want to pollute your Ember Data model with visible attributes (because they aren't backend data) you can also use an array proxy or object proxy to hold those values

Answer (score 2):

#### 1 hide/show content inside an each loop

The best thing for that is to use a component:

```
{{#each foos as |foo|}}
  {{foo-item foo=foo}}
{{/each}}
```

Then you can the same technique you already know for a single item inside the component.

#### 2 do animations

A good way here is the addon [ember-liquid-fire](http://ember-animation.github.io/liquid-fire/).

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestion!